# I have encountered problem when installing phidget

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have followed the step given by ros wiki. Everything was alright until to set up the udev rules for the phidgets usb devices. After enter [sh src/phidgets_drivers/phidgets_api/share/setup-udev.sh], I have the following error,

```
cp: cannot stat ‘udev/99-phidgets.rules’: No such file or directory
Phidgets udev rules file has been copied to /etc/udev/rules.d/
```

Any kind soul can render help to solve this issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271709/i-have-encountered-problem-when-installing-phidget/) by [gambit](https://answers.ros.org/users/32009/gambit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The script makes an assumption about the location of the rules in relation to the working directory. https://github.com/ros-drivers/phidgets_drivers/blob/kinetic/phidgets_api/share/setup-udev.sh#L1

I'd suggest trying:

```
cd src/phidgets_drivers/phidgets_api/share/ && sh setup-udev.sh
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gambit](https://answers.ros.org/users/32009/gambit/) on 2017-10-02**:
Thank you so much. This command has cleared. but I cant find the launch file for high speed encoder. Is there a pre-set launch file or I have to manually create a new launch file?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-10-02**:
That's a new question. Please accept this answer and ask it as a new question and make sure to include more information. This doesn't currently have enough information for me to understand what you want to do: http://wiki.ros.org/Support

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-10-02**:
Also a PR to fix the documentation I'm sure would be appreciated by the maintainers.

**Comment by [gambit](https://answers.ros.org/users/32009/gambit/) on 2017-10-02**:
Thank you tfoote. My question has been answered.